# Can you mass edit all files returned in a grep?

Tags: search, vim, command-line, sed, grep

I want to mass-edit a ton of files that are returned in a grep. (I know, I should get better at sed).

So if I do:

```
grep -rnI 'xg_icon-*'
```

How do I pipe all of those files into vi?

Comment: but doesn't vi only open one file at once?

Comment: No. You can open multiple files at once.  The commands :next and :prev will cycle through the argument list.  With actual vi, you'll have to save before changing files.  With Vim, you can ":set hidden" to change buffers without needing to save first, but still get warned if you attempt to exit with unsaved changes.  Also, Vim has :bnext and :bprev commands to go through the buffer list, which is a superset of the argument list.

Comment: One other thing to mention is that if you're editing huge numbers of files with vim, you can use something like the BufExplorer vim plugin to review which buffers you have open and flick between them quickly.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The easiest way is to have grep return just the filenames (`-l` instead of `-n`) that match the pattern.  Run that in a subshell and feed the results to Vim.

```
vim $(grep -rIl 'xg_icon-*' *)
```

Comment: Also note that vim doesn't like it when standard input is from a pipe, so the above is much better than 'grep -rIl ... | vim'.

Comment: Vim is happy with standard input when you invoke it with `vim -`

Comment: @Kaleb vim works very well when it comes from a pipe. Just don't forget the call to xargs, in that case. When the pipe fills vim with contents and not filenames, the paid nerd answered your remark: don't forget the dash.

Comment: Usually after a `grep ...` giving me the correct results, I do a `vi $(!! -l)`. Works probably on all modern Bash, but if I remember not on MSysGit/Cygwin.

Comment: @Wernight that is A+.

Answer (score 27):

A nice general solution to this is to use xargs to convert a stdout from a process like grep to an argument list.

A la:

```
grep -rIl 'xg_icon-*' | xargs vi
```

Comment: Very helpful answer for me, not least since it generalizes to programs that aren't `vi`. (Some of us aren't of that tribe, but most questions of this variety point that way fairly explicitly.)

Comment: On my mac (in Terminal), after executing this with vim, my Terminal had some funky problems with stdin. Not the case with other solutions. Characters weren't shown visibly, etc. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

if you use vim and the -p option, it will open each file in a tab, and you can switch between them using gt or gT, or even the mouse if you have mouse support in the terminal

Answer (score 8):

You can do it without any processing of the grep output! This will even enable you to go the the right line (using `:help quickfix` commands, eg. `:cn` or `:cw`). So, if you are using bash or zsh:

```
vim -q <(grep foo *.c)
```

Comment: vim -q -c copen <(grep foo *.c) seems to be even better

Answer (score 2):

if what you want to edit is similar across all files, then no point using vi to do it manually. (although vi can be scripted as well), hypothetically, it looks something like this, since you never mention what you want to edit

```
grep -rnI 'xg_icon-*' | while read FILE
do
    sed -i.bak 's/old/new/g' $FILE # (or other editing commands, eg awk... )
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vi `grep -l -i findthisword *`
```