# Running a search command as soon as vim opens?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to run a search command as soon as gvim opens?

I'm thinking of using something similar to

```
vim $(grep -rl 'refreshents' .)
```

[source question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716470/can-you-mass-edit-all-files-returned-in-a-grep)

and then searching for the first result in the first buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brain Agnew answer is spot on. However it might be helpful to use the `:argdo` command to run a command over each file supplied to vim from the command line. This list is called the argslist.

```
:argdo %s/foo/bar/g|w
```

I think I would approach this from the other direction. That is open up vim then search via `:grep` or `:vimgrep`. Then walk though the quickfix list. There are some nice vimcast about this issue. [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/) and [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/).

```
:vimgrep/foo/
:Cdo s/foo/bar/g|w
```

Where `:Cdo` is defined as:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=command Cdo try | sil cfirst |
    \ while 1 | exec <q-args> | sil cn | endwhile |
    \ catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E\%(553\|42\):/ |
    \ endtry
```

For more help see:

```
:h :argdo
:h :vimgrep
:h :grep
:h quickfix
```

Comment: You could also do something like `vim -c "vimgrep 'refreshents' *"`.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply do it from the command line ?

```
$ vim myfile.java +/pattern
```

From [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vim-arguments):

> +/{pat}       The cursor will be positioned on the first line containing "pat" in the first file being edited